# MSAT and IMSAT problems (restricted versions of SAT)

Tags: complexity-theory, satisfiability

I was reading about [about NP-intermediate problems on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-intermediate#cite_note-6) and saw the IMSAT problem mentioned over there.

There is no Wikipedia page for that problem and they only cite [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2588166_Hypergraph_Transversal_Computation_and_Related_Problems_in_Logic_and_AI).

In the paper they define the MSAT problem as:

> Recall that the satisfiability problem (SAT) is to decide whether a set of
> propositional clauses $C = \{C_1, ... ,C_m\}$, where each $C_i$ is a set of literals, on
> atoms $X = \{x_1, ... , x_n \}$ is satisfied by some truth assignment to $X$. Its restriction $MSAT$, where every clause of $C$ must be either positive or negative, i.e.,
> must not contain any negative or positive literal, respectively, is still NP-hard.

But they don't reference any source that prove $MSAT$ is indeed NP-Hard. Can you please enlighten me?

Moreover, they later introduce the problem of IMSAT by:

> The first subcase of MSAT which we consider is made up of instances
> with the property that every pair of a positive clause and a negative
> clause resolves, i.e. there is an atoms which occurs unnegated in the
> positive and negated in the negative clause.

I don't understand why Wikipedia mentioned this problem as NP-intermediate, this term was never shown in the paper. I see they prove that co-IMSAT is TRANS-HYP-complete, but couldn'tunderstand if TRANS-HYP is NP-intermediate, and what does it say on IMSAT.

I got a mess here, and I couldn't find any other sources.
Is MSAT NP-Hard? I would like to see a proof (or at least an idea for a proof)
Is IMSAT NP-intermediate? A proof of that seems to be missing as well, or I totally didn't understand the paper.

And another a bit more general question about using NP-intermediate problems:

If I understand correctly, it is quiet impossible to prove something is in NP-intermediate, since the class is defined as problems that polynomial running time solution was not found for them, and they were not proven to be NP-Hard (though they are in NP). If I want to "lean" on IMSAT as NP-intermediate. how can I do that?

Lets say I have a reduction from IMSAT to my problem P, which means if P is solvable in polynomial time, IMSAT as well. What paper can I cite to show that IMSAT in NP-intermediate - which can convince people P is a hard problem (and it is fair to use approximate/probabilistic algorithm instead of trying to solve it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, I'll give an elementary proof for the $\mathsf{NP}$-hardness of $\mathrm{MSAT}$ by reduction from $\mathrm{SAT}$.

Let $\varphi$ be a propositional formula in CNF (i.e., a $\mathrm{SAT}$ instance) consisting of the clauses $C_1, ..., C_m$ and let $C_i^+$ and $C_i^-$ denote the set of positive and negative literals of the clause $C_i$, respectively.

I illustrate the idea using an example:
Suppose we have a clause $C = (x_1 \vee x_2 \vee \neg x_3)$. The idea will be to introduce a new literal $c$ to split $C$ into $C^+ \cup \{c\}$ and $C^- \cup \{\neg c\}$ to obtain two new clauses which are either positive or negative.
In this example, we get $(x_1 \vee x_2 \vee c) \wedge (\neg c \vee \neg x_3)$, and it is not hard to see that this formula is indeed equivalent to $C$ itself: Any satisfying assignment of $C$ must satisfy at least one of our two new clauses, and by choosing the assignment to $c$ accordingly, we can satisfy both. Conversely, any assignment to $c$ can only satisfy one of the clauses and hence, a satisfying assignment to both clauses must, if restricted to the variables $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$, satisfy $C$.

By applying this construction to all clauses, we obtain a formula $\varphi'$ which is equivalent to $\varphi$ but only contains positive and negative clauses.
Clearly, $\varphi'$ can be computed from $\varphi$ in polynomial time, and we conclude that $\mathrm{MSAT}$ is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard.

On the second question (and the ones following): We do not know *any* $\mathsf{NP}$-intermediate problems (that is why the section title in the linked Wiki article contains "might"). By Ladner's theorem, such problems exist if and only if $\mathsf P \neq \mathsf{NP}$, which is an open question. Hence, you probably won't find papers showing (unconditionally) that $\mathrm{IMSAT}$ is $\mathsf{NP}$-intermediate.

One can speculate that problems which have evaded the $\mathsf P$/$\mathsf{NP}$-completeness classification for a long time could be intermediate, but speculation it is. In some cases, like the Graph Isomorphism problem, better arguments than "it hasn't been resolved either way for a long time" can be made: Under common complexity-theoretic assumptions (specifically, a non-collapse of the polynomial hierarchy), graph isomorphism is not $\mathsf{NP}$-hard. On the other hand, much research has been invested into finding polynomial-time algorithms for GI, yielding to many such algorithms for special cases and a general quasi-polynomial-time algorithm recently developed by László Babai.

I am not aware of similar "evidence" for $\mathrm{IMSAT}$, though it is not my field of expertise -- maybe someone else can expand on that.